# Loading html partials from different domain in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors

I want to be able to load html partials from amazon s3 so i upload them and used the public urls like so;

```
'use strict';

/* App Module */

var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'phonecatAnimations',

  'phonecatControllers',
  'phonecatFilters',
  'phonecatServices'
]);

phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/playfield/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/playfield/phone-detail.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/phones'
      });
  }]);
```

But i get an error like this

```
 [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.
```

when i switch to a partial from like domain like this;

```
templateUrl: '/partials/phone-list.html'
```

it works just fine.

I would be glad for any help.
Thanks

Comment: It's a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is to solve the problem on your server side, which is not subject to CORS. You write a small proxy service that, depending on the URL, forwards the requests to other predefined servers.

So, for instance, any request directed to /playfield/ will be redirected to a specific host, like s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com using a specific protocol (either http or https).

Whatever the request returns is what you return to your client.

This way you can now safely obtain all content from your own server and your client requests will not be subject to CORS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I thinking there may be a lag in such a setup, would you recommend such a setup in a production system?

Comment: @elimence We'll the company I work for uses this approach in several production systems, using a node.js server as the proxy. And I know other colleagues doing the same in their systems. Mostly because besides avoiding CORS it has other advantages, like now your server can control security. You don't want to let your client control what is accessible and what is not. Of course the proxy implies an extra step that will add some delay, but if you have a good broadband and good resources on your server that is probably negligible.

Comment: I'm curious, can you tell me if there's any special reason why you don't host the files on your main server and request them from there?
Thanks